# Send request with local storage parameters?

Tags: python, request, local-storage

I need to have direct access to a certain part of a website, that needs you to log in

I created an account and obtained its token, but for me to send the request, I need that token in the local storage.

Is it possible with python to either have local storage or somehow mimic it?

I was thinking local storage could have something to do with headers

Comment: Local storage is not directly related to authentication. It might store a token but the authentication will typically happen by HTTP headers. You can store the token elsewhere.

Comment: You can add it in the headers, or you can provide a URL for others to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an library named localStoragePy `pip install localStoragePy`. You can read more about it at [Click Here](https://pypi.org/project/localStoragePy/).

You can even use your local files using numpy for writing and reading the data locally.

If you want to store and save data in a database then I will suggest using MongoDB or Firebase.